# Implementing multiple instances of a concurrent queue

Tags: c#, .net, concurrent-queue

I'm trying to work with .NET ConcurrentQueue but I'm having some trouble. This is the situation I'm trying to accomplish.

When my application loads I will load a Queue with 1000 objects.  When the user clicks a button it will take the first object in the queue....do some work...and then pass the item to the next queue.  The queues go in order so when queue1 is done it pass it on to queue2, and queue2 to queue3 etc.

I can have upto 100 queues.

I thought ConcurrentQueue would be the best way to do this, however, I'm not too sure how to go about this.

Comment: You are building a pipeline,  concurrentQueue is good approach,  but read about pipelines,  for example signal processing pipeline.

Comment: If you tell us more about what this code really does in the larger context we can answer better. Many answers are possible here.